# Routes with optional params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to setup a route that looks like this: `acme.com/posts/:category/:status`. Both `:category` and `:status` are optional. I wrote many variations, but none worked:

```
resources :posts do
  match '(/:category)(/:status)', to: 'posts#index', as: 'filter', on: :collection
end

# Category Links
link_to "Questions", filter_posts_path(:questions)
link_to "Suggestions", filter_posts_path(:suggestions)

# Status Links
link_to "Published", filter_posts_path(params[:category], :published)
link_to "Draft", filter_posts_path(params[:category], :draft)
```

The idea is to be able to *1) filter by category*, *2) filter by status*, *and 3) filter by both category and status if both are available*. The current setup has also broken my `/posts/new` path, always redirecting to `posts#index`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use just `resources :posts` and send the filter params in the query string? (e.g. `acme.com/posts?category=foo&status=bar`)

Comment: I want to pretty up the URL so it appears `/posts/:category/:status/` or at least `/posts/category/:category/status/:status`

Answer (score 2):

I had this variation and it seems working fine:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :posts, :except => [:show] do
      collection do
        get "/(:category(/:status))", to: "posts#index", as: "list", :constraints => lambda{|req|
          req.env["PATH_INFO"].to_s !~ /new|\d/i
        }
      end
    end
  end
```

= CONTROLLER=admin/posts rake route

```
list_admin_posts GET    /admin/posts(/:category(/:status))(.:format)                 admin/posts#index
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the more RESTful `resources :posts` (in config/routes.rb) and send the params in the query string.

With that approach, all parameters are optional and you're not limited to using predefined parameters.

Comment: I think I will do that just because this is proving to be far more trouble than it's worth, but it would be nice to have `/posts/:category/:status/ or at least /posts/category/:category/status/:status` instead of the query param...

Answer (score 0):

Do this works for you?

```
resources :posts do
  collection do
    match '/:category(/:status)', to: 'posts#index', as: 'filter'
    match '/:status', to: 'posts#index', as: 'filter'
  end
end
```

Hope at least it helps!

Comment: That raises an error `No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :status=>nil, :format=>:under_consideration}`... not sure how format is creeping in there for, that should be status... inverting, which I originally did, so that the bottom route matches category raises a similar error!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
match '/filter/*category_or_status' => 'posts#index', as: 'filter'
```

With this you can build your own filter path. Then you could parse `params[:category_or_status]` in your controller and get the category or status if they are  given.